# JBoss 6 EAP, how can I change the module load order?

Tags: java, jboss

I'm running JBoss 6.1 EAP, one of the default modules has its own version of the org/omg/CORBA/ORB.class file, I want to use my own jar for that file.  I've tried including it in my app's war file but it is still picking up the one from the JBoss module.

So the question is, what is the load order of modules in JBoss and how can I change it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include a [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) file with your artifact, and configure the file to exclude the container's CORBA impl.

Below is an example which will exclude log4j

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```